# Remove first div in parent div causes all inner divs to be removed too

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
<div id="main" style="background:#aaaaaa;float:left;height:160px;margin:5px;position:relative;display:block;width:630px;">
        <div id="1" class="item" style="background:#ffaacc;float:left;width:200px;height:150px;margin:5px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;">
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="item" style="background:#aaccff;float:left;width:200px;height:150px;margin:5px;position:absolute;left:210px;top:0px;">
        </div>
        <div id="3" class="item" style="background:#ffccaa;float:left;width:200px;height:150px;margin:5px;position:absolute;left:420px;top:0px;">
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove first div in #main after some animation

I wrote jquery

```
$('#leftbutton').click(function() {
            $('#main').append('<div id='+ i++ +' class="item" style="background:#ffccaa;float:left;width:200px;height:150px;margin:5px;position:absolute;left:630px;top:0px;z-index:1"></div>');
            $('.item').animate({
                "left": "-=210px"
            }, 200, function(){
                $('#main div:first-child').remove();
            });
        });
});
```

But it also removes all other divs. I only want to delete 1st div, how can i do that

example http://jsfiddle.net/Ks6K6/2/

**EDIT**

I needed to save the reference for the first element then do animation for all divs and after that remove the first div by reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem you have is that you're animating on **all** of your child elements, and for each of those animations, you're passing a callback that executes when it completes that removes the first element. You're essentially doing "remove the first element" `x` number of times, where `x` is the number of elements being animated.

So the first elements animation completes, removing the first child. The second elements animation completes, and it also removes the first child (what was previously the second child), etc.

I would store the reference to the specific element you want to remove before calling `.animate()`, then use that variable to perform the removal.

```
$('#leftbutton').click(function() {
    $('#main').append('<div id=' + i+++' class="item" style="background:#ffccaa;float:left;width:200px;height:150px;margin:5px;position:absolute;left:630px;top:0px;z-index:1"></div>');
    var $firstElement = $('#main div:first');
    $('.item').animate({
        "left": "-=210px"
    }, 200, function() {
       $firstElement.remove();
    });
});
```

[Broken DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9D9W/1/)

[Fixed DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9D9W/2/)

Comment: I can't mark the answer as useful cause i need 15 reputation sorry

Comment: @ArmeniaH No worries, as long as the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('div#main div').first().remove();
```

Comment: All other divs are also deleted :(

Comment: If you use `$('#main div:first-child').remove();` it works the same so that's not the issue

Comment: What I think is that event has it's own context with only one div of class ".item" and this div is then in fact first. So what's happening is not that other divs are deleted along with first but all divs are deleted one by one.

Comment: Aaah, ofcourse its deleting all! It goes in loop through all .item elements. Firts pass - deletes first div. Then it goes to second item - and delete new first div which was second before. And it goes like this through all divs.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) instead of [first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/). first gets the first matching only, first-child gets any matching element.

```
$('#leftbutton').click(
   function() { 
       $('#main').append(''); 
       $('.item').animate({ "left": "-=210px" }, 200, function(){ $('.item:first').remove(); 
       }); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the selector, it should be "item:first"

Answer (score 0):

Try using the first selector instead of first child, see http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

```
$('#main div:first').remove();
```

UPDATE:

Ok, have you tried removing like this:

```
$('.item').animate({
            "left": "-=210px"
        }, 200, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        })
```

Comment: It deletes all other divs ... when i don't specify class="item" it works, but i need to specify same class for the item ...

Comment: the same result, all divs are deleted, cause they have the same class

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $("#main div").eq(0).remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/tmnUC/1/)

Comment: @Ajinkya It's working in your demo that is nothing like the actual situation described in the question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I just removed `style` anyways I have updated demo with code given in question

Comment: @Ajinkya The question includes an animation with a callback on a set of elements, you're just calling a single line of code.